# How to get a table multiple cell value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

I have a table with multiple rows:

```
<tr>
    <td>Ask 1</td>
    <td id="92-1">92,1</td>
    <td id="92-2">92,2</td>
    <td id="92-3">92,3</td>
    <td id="92-4">92,4</td>
    <td id="92-5">92,5</td>
    <td id="92-6">92,6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ask 2</td>
    <td id="93-1">93,1</td>
    <td id="93-2">93,2</td>
    <td id="93-3">93,3</td>
    <td id="93-4">93,4</td>
    <td id="93-5">93,5</td>
    <td id="93-6">93,6</td>
</tr>
```

I use this function for select (color) 1 cell / row

```
$('td').click( function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td').each( function( index, element ) {
    $(element).removeClass('on');
   });
   $(this).addClass('on');
});
```

I would like to recover the values selected in a array.

In this function I tested

```
// $('table tr td').each(function(){
//  if($(this).hasClass('on')) {
//      value.push(id);
//     }
// });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var value = $('table tr td.on').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2):

```
$('table tr td.on').get(); // returns a linear array of DOM nodes
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ! I had not thought of get(); for return values